# When does authorization occur during app login?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I'm currently building the login/registration part of an application (similar to WhatsApp login).

The flow is as follows:

1. Screen #1: User enters phone number for authentication
2. Screen #2: the user will need to enter a 4 digit number (which was sent via SMS) to verify the phone number
3. Screen #3: In the case where the user is a new user, s/he will enter the full name. If the user is a returning user, screen #3 will not show up (jump to screen #4).
4. Screen #4: User is taken to the home screen of the app.

My question here is: will the access token and the refresh token be returned in screen #2 from phone verification API OR in screen #3 from entering the full name API?

I also want to know what the return value of phone verification and entering full name APIs.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand your question, but how does it relate to OAuth 2?

Comment: I work on Restful Web Service and I follow Oauth2 principals so my question is which api should return access token and refresh token #2 or #3.
Or please give me a short illustration of WhatsApp login and registration APIs in the above listed screens.

Comment: Look at this tutorial. It might help you: 
 https://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/